# How to add Web Services to Netty-Server?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, netty

I have developed a netty server based on low-level tcp/ip protocols. Now this server is supposed to also handle web service calls (jax-ws). Does anyone know where to go from here?

I've read nearly all posts on netty+ws but I have to admit the information provided is just not clear enough for me.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: Here is what I have done. I used embedded jetty like http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld and then integrated my web service as shown in http://jectbd.com/?p=1624 Finally I read the source code of HttpTunnelingServlet and wrote my own netty-tunneling-client-stub that than can create channels on web service calls. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Restlet have support for Netty:
http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/netty/package-summary.html

You can also use Xitrum, which has feature similar to JAX-RS:
http://ngocdaothanh.github.com/xitrum/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I've already found some libraries like RESTeasy, GlassFish JAX-WS, JBoss-WS and so on. But those seem to need servlet containers and are based on the inversion of control pattern. Basically that is what I don't know how to combine with my existing stand-alone server.

Comment: You can also embed Jetty or Tomcat to your stand-alone server. New versions of them are said to be easily embedded.

Comment: Like I said, I have read most of the articles about it and all those buzz words are known to me. But I think I am looking for some minimalistic 5-point-tutorial for example. Servlet container, netty, web service jax-ws and the netty HttpTunnelingServlet are words I have heard and read about. But I don't know how to bring them together in a way that makes sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), especially since they use Netty as a native I/O provider, I think.